# django model to yeild specific HTML output without redundancy in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 3 models **(supervisor, students, and allocation)**
I am building an allocation system where multiple students can be allocated to one supervisor
Now I want my model to be able to yeld this output

[Example of how i want the output to come out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQZmW.png)

Here are the structure of my model

`class StudentProfile(models.Model):`

```
stud_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
user_id = models.OneToOneField(User,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
programme_id = models.ForeignKey(Programme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
session_id = models.ForeignKey(Sessi`**enter code here**`on, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
type_id = models.ForeignKey(StudentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dept_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`class SupervisorProfile(models.Model):`

```
super_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dept_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`class Allocate(models.Model):`

```
allocate_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
stud_id = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
super_id = models.ForeignKey(SupervisorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

now my main focus is the Allocate model where the allocation is made, and there is a lot of redundancy any suggestions on how to improve my model to remove redundancy in yielding the expected HTML output would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to assign several students to one Supervisor
For this, you only need to use ***ForeignKey*** in class ***StudentProfile***
As below:
`supervisor=models.ForeignKey(Supervisor,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)`
But if you need to connect a student to several Supervisor, you should use ***ManyToManyField***
ManyToManyField automatically creates a third table like *class Allocate* of  yourself
For more information, refer to the [hire](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).
It is also possible to reduce the redundancy by considering the department.
However
It doesn't seem that less redundancy can be found in *sql database*
I hope it was useful